# How to calculate the shortest path to pass on 7.000 UTM points?

Tags: distance, utm, travelling-salesman, shortest-path

Anyone can give me an advice how to calculate the shortest path with a lot of UTM points?
In total I have 7000 points, but it can be grouping 100 or 500.

I have knowledges about Java and Python for develope an script if it's necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that you want to do is to solve [Travelling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) or one of its variations. 7000 points is **a very difficult task**. And you may spent a lot time calculating it (depending on software and algorithm)

There is an open-source implementation of Genetic algorithm (not the most advanced one) in [pgRouting extension](http://pgrouting.org/index.html#) for PostGIS.

Another option is [Concorde](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/concorde.html) - a solid, state of the art software for TSP that uses branch-and-cut method (and AFIK is able to run custom algorithms). It is free for academic use. Concorde is definitely capable of solving your task.

Also there are *Lin–Kernighan* (LK) method and the *stem-and-cycle* (S&C) method for TSP solving which demonstrate remarkable results (see for example this article: [César Rego, Dorabela Gamboa, Fred Glover, Colin Osterman (2011) Traveling salesman problem heuristics: Leading methods, implementations and latest advances. *European Journal of Operational Research*. 211, 427–441, doi:10.1016/j.ejor.2010.09.010](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377221710006065)), but I'm unaware about corresponding software.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to test with 50-100-200 points with [python tsp-solver](https://github.com/dmishin/tsp-solver)